# emacs regex match uppercase word

Tags: regex, emacs

I have a document to typeset from plain ascii that is currently using UPPERCASE for emphasis. I'm trying to do a `M-x query-replace-regexp` to take the uppercase WORD & replace it with `\emph{lowercase word}` (i.e. change the case of 'word' not isert the string 'lowercase'). I can do the substitution with `\\emph{\1}`, but I could not make `\,(downcase \1)` (as per [my reading of] the docs) work for some reason (the case of the word is untouched, although substituting `capitalise` does work as expected, and I am at a loss as to how to match uppercase words.

If anyone was feeling particularly kind, is there any way to match *all* uppercase words untill a lowercase word, so that I could wrap the lot inside one `\emph{}`?

Many thanks in advance. I've read the docs, but after an hour of trying to understand regular expressions my head hurts and I've got nowhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `query-replace-regexp`
- `\([A-Z][A-Z \n]*[A-Z]\)`
- `\\emph{\,(downcase \1)}`

Note that you need to actually do <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> instead of `\n` in the regex.

Comment: thanks, that did everything I wanted it to do. Of course, it matches the first letter of the next word if that's capital, but I can live with that. at some point I might work out how it works

Comment: Why not just use `\<\([A-Z]+\)\>` if you're concerned about matching full words?

Comment: @Inaimathi, you regex doesn't match multiple words separated by spaces at once.

Comment: True, but it would match each individual all-caps word, and it wouldn't counter-intuitively match something like `FOO Bar`

Comment: @Inaimathi, each individual all-caps wasn't what was asked for. I prefer not to complect things, especially when explaining to a newbie.

Comment: @abo-abo The newbie is grateful for the lack of complication :)